# Domain of definition of an infinite series of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I was given the function,
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n}\cos^n{x}\sin{nx}}
$$
and was asked to prove that it is well defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

I tried to prove that by showing that the series $(\sum{f_n})_{1 \leq n}$ converges, with
$$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\cos^n{x}\sin{nx}$$
But I could not to figure out a way to do so. How do I prove its convergence?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint : Forget the sine for the time being and let $\cos(x)=t$

Comment: Without $\sin nx$, root test can help prove the absolute convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\cos^nx$$ for the case $|\cos x |\neq 1$.

Comment: @LiKwokKeung Thank you for your help. I will try using your method.